# Count unique values in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm pretty much an Access n00b, but I've built a basic database for a friend's school to keep track of students seeing the counselling team. They're all pretty happy with it, but they've asked if it's possible to quickly see how many students each counselor is seeing.
I have tables set up for staff, students, and case notes, and I thought it would be easy to create a query that does this, but I cant get it to work; it keeps returning the number of case notes per staff member, rather than the students:
[Query right now. Staff #7 has seen one student twice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afXLQ.png)

What I'd like it to do is tell me how many students each counselor is seeing, based on the case notes they've entered.

I'm really hoping for a solution I can implement in design view, rather than SQL.

You can DL the database if you want to look at it:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RvbnEcKEagZldJMDZkZmkybkk/view?usp=sharing

(It's all dummy data)

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer me.

Comment: Can you add your query to the question? Also, it helps to give the output you are getting and the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to say, "count distinct," but apparently that's not a thing in Access.

Instead, you'll need to run two queries that are the equivalent of

```
select StaffID, FirstName, LastName, count(*)
from (
  select distinct StaffID, FirstName, LastName, Student
  from TblStaff stf join TblCaseNote nte on nte.Staff = stf.StaffID
) foo
group by StaffID, FirstName, LastName
```

The first query should have StaffID, FirstName, LastName, and Student, each set to Group By.

[image]

Then create another query that has the first as its source and Group By all columns except Student, which you should count.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! If you're ever in my neck of the woods, I'll buy you a beer.